# Lotus Notes: Calculating Hours including the next day

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I am calculating the sum of hours between two fields: `TimeIn` and `TimeOut`, the result will display on my computed for display field `hoursWorked`. The problem is, when I input `15:00` on the first field and `01:00` on the second field, it doesn't display anything. I tried putting a `@If` to execute two calculations that if `TimeOut` is less than `TimeIn` it will use the first action, but still nothing. Here's my code:

```
thours:=@If(@IsNull(TimeIn) | @IsNull(TimeOut)=""; @Return(""); "" );
seconds := @If(TimeOut < Timein;(24 + TimeIn) - TimeOut; TimeIn - TimeOut);
hours := @Integer(seconds/3600);
minutes := @Integer(@Modulo(seconds;3600)/60);
output := @Right("00" + @Text(hours); 2) + ":" + @Right("00" + @Text(minutes); 2);
@TextToTime(output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the seconds this way:

```
seconds := TimeOut - TimeIn;
seconds := @If(seconds < 0; seconds + 24*3600; seconds);
```

Whenever `TimeOut` is smaller then `TimeIn` it is assumed that the time frame goes from one day to the next day.

Examples:

```
TimeIn   TimeOut   hoursWorked
15:00    01:00     10:00
15:00    14:45     23:45
15:00    17:00     02:00
```

Comment: Wow Knut! You've helped me out here again. Thank you so much for this.